Asymptotic stability by comparison with another system
Consider a nonlinear system of the form
$$ \dot{x} = f(x)x, $$
with $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. I know that there exists an asymptotically stable linear system of same dimenstion $\dot{y} = Ay$ for which it holds that
$$\Vert \dot{x} \Vert \leq \Vert \dot{y} \Vert $$
whenever $x = y$. Does this imply that the nonlinear system is also asymptotically stable?
My guess is no, due to the nonlinearity of $f$. Even starting at the same $x(0) = y(0) = a_0$ and despite the norm condition, due to the nonlinearity it may happen that $y(T)<x(T)$ due to different dynamics and different state trajectories. However, I'm aware that this is not a proof.

Have you considered $f(x)=0$?

@SassatelliGiulio sorry that was a typo, I corrected it

@RollenS.D'Souza if $f(x_r) = 0$, then $\dot{x}_r =0$ and $x(t) = x_r$ for all $t \geq t_r$

Right. So if f=0 ...then Is that system asymptotically stable or just stable?

@RollenS.D'Souza if $f(x_r)=0$ if and only if $x_r = 0$, then may be asymptotically stable. Else, $x=0$ may only be stable

So... that kind of answers my question. In general, asymptotic stability of $y=0$ does not imply as. stability of $x=0$, at least without more conditions on $f$. But what if $f(x)=0$ if and only if $x=0$? :D

Another counter example is $f(x)=-0.9,A$. Namely, now it can be shown that $\dot{x}=f(x)x$ is unstable (since its time reverse is stable).

The equilibrium condition (x) = 0 implies stability but not necessarily asymptotic stability.

The linear system $\dot{y}=Ay$ is asymptotically stable if all the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ have negative real parts. This implies that for any initial condition $y(0)$, the solution $y(t)$ will tend to 0 as $t\to\infty.$
Given the norm condition $\|\dot{x}\|\leq\|\dot{y}\|$,we can analyze the stability of the nonlinear system. Consider a candidate Lyapunov function $V(x)=\frac12\|x\|^2$. The time derivative along the
trajectories of the nonlinear system is:
$$\dot{V}(x)=\frac d{dt}\left(\frac12\|x\|^2\right)=x^T\dot{x}=x^Tf(x)x.$$
For the linear system, a similar Lyapunov function yields:
$$\dot{V}(y)=y^T\dot{y}=y^TAy.$$
Given that the linear system is asymptotically stable, $A$ is a Hurwitz matrix, which implies
$y^TAy<0$ for all $y\neq0.$
Comparison of Derivatives:
By the norm condition:
$$\|\dot{x}\|\leq\|\dot{y}\|.$$
This implies that the rate of change of the state in the nonlinear system is bounded by the rate of change in the linear system. However, this alone does not ensure that the trajectories of $x(t)$ will converge to 0 because it does not directly provide information  because it does not directly provide information about the sign of $x^T\dot{x}=x^Tf(x)x$.
